# upgrading from angular4 to angular5,package.jsoon chnages

Tags: migration, angular5, package.json

I want to upgrade my application from angular4 to angular5. What changes do I need to make in `package.json`?

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material/fab": "^0.28.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "1.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "1.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "1.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "1.0.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.1.1",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "1.5.4",
    "angular-tree-component": "4.1.0",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "3.1.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "mydatepicker": "2.0.27",
    "ng-sidebar": "6.0.1",
    "ng2-device-detector": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "4.2.0",
    "ng2-dropdown-treeview": "2.0.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "4.0.3",
    "ng2draggable": "1.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.9.3",
    "ngx-clipboard": "8.0.4",
    "primeng": "4.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
}, "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "8.0.22",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you, from my experince, to create a new project with the newest @angular/cli and copy your code there. It will be more easier than configuring angular 5, specially if you have ejected your project, because the webpack configurations are pretty different, and you will get a lot of wierd errors by just updating packages.

Answer (score 0):

just follow this command

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

you have to upgrade your Angular CLI to avoid some conflict 
this command gonna upgrade your global package

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
# if npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean` 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and this command will upgrade your local package

```
rm -rf node_modules dist  <-- in mac os
# use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist <--- in Windows Command Prompt;
use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist <--- in Windows PowerShell 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

I used to upgrade project from angular 4 to angular 5, and i got a little bug cause i use some library that deprecate in angular 4, 
so my suggestion is backup your project and try to upgrade it !!
Lol, hope your enjoy :)

P.S. i'm copy this code from somewhere and didn't save path sorry for didn't give a credit of this code

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall and Reinstall on that time you wants to give the

```
npm install @angular/Cli @5.2.9
```

Which version you need that's. Version

Then after Remove the nodemodules in project and then click

```
npm install
```

Then the package.json is automatically upgrades to  5